# Cannot resolve plugin con maven en java

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Tengo un problema con maven en java, no me deja ejecutarlo, me dan los siguientes problemas:

> Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6
>
> Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4
>
> Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1
>
> Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4
>
> Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4
>
> Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7
>
> Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3

He estado buscando soluciones y algunos hablan de buscar aquí maven y seleccionarlo pero me salen las siguientes opciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo pom.xml dentro del proyecto también:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien puede ayudarme lo agradecería.

Comment: Instala neatbeans 12 que ya trae maven y todo metido y prueba asi sabremos si es elprograma o el proyecto

Comment: También me da error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316339/how-to-solve-maven-2-6-resource-plugin-dependency
mira la carpeta m2 de maven que tendras en el sistema

Comment: Puedes compartir tu archivo settings que está en tu m2? Además de la traza competa, ya que algo me dice que estás tratando de conectarte a maven central con el protocolo equivocado.

Answer (score 0):

Para las versiones más recientes se recomienda activar la opción para usar el registro del plugin

1. File> settings
2. Build>execution>deployment>build tools>Maven
3. Verifica que esté activa la opción: usé plugin registry
4. Ok>apply

Te recomiendo reiniciar la aplicación después de aplicar.

Si el problema continua intenta reseteado  el caché

1. File> invalidate caches/restart

Answer (score 0):

Después de varias opciones (ver: [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20496239/maven-plugins-can-not-be-found-in-intellij)), a mí lo que me funcionó fue ejecutar 'Run Maven Build' de la fase **site** (esto hizo que se instalaran los plugins que faltaban).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).